# Customized trigger field breaks resizability of the browser window

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have created a custom textfield which can also show trigger icons *before* the input field.

However, it seems I am missing something important, because now the viewport does no longer resize when the browser window is resized.

I have made a fiddle that exhibits the problem:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/299f

Comment: I don't have a solution, but here is a hint that maybe will help you. If you comment the 30 and 41 lines in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/299i) (an empty `for in` statement), it will work. This is really, really odd

Comment: @scebotari66 Yes, in fact it's just the `Trigger.create` line, but that's exactly the part [which I copied from the original triggers code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Text.js.html#line788).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have introduced a global `id` property in your `applyIcons` function. It's likely clobbering some local variable elsewhere.